# Dialog box keeps asking for password

Tags: exchange-2007, password

I am running Windows 7, Outlook 2007 (Office 2007 pro) and I'm connecting to our Exchange Server 2007 which is part of Small Business Server 2008.

Outlook 2007 on one client keeps asking for the password to the remote access URL. If I simply click cancel it's OK for a few minutes. Entering the password and clicking the save PW box does no good. Sometimes clicking cancel results in another dilog box asking the same thing and I may have to click cancel several times to get it to go away for a while. Occasionally Outlook may actually go into a mode where it says it needs the password typed so I click the link which brings the dialog back but simply clicking cancel will make Outlook connect again.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Continous prompting in Outlook Anywhere

There is an issue when you enabled NTLM authentication in Outlook Anywhere when Exchange is installed on Windows 2008.

By default, Kernel Mode Authentication is enabled in IIS 7.0 on the Client Access server (CAS). To resolve this issue, disable Kernel Mode Authentication for Client Access servers that are running Windows Server 2008

1. open  a command prompt window
2. cd \%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\
3. AppCmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /useKernelMode:false

When you have the Outlook Anywhere feature configured on a Windows Server 2008-based computer that is running Terminal Services Gateway, you may experience the following symptoms:

If you enable Outlook Anywhere before you install Terminal Services Gateway, users cannot connect to their Exchange mailboxes by using RPC over HTTP.

If you enable Outlook Anywhere after you install Terminal Services Gateway, Outlook Anywhere users can connect to Exchange by using RPC over HTTP. However, after you open the TS Gateway Manager snap-in, Outlook Anywhere users can no longer connect to Exchange by using RPC over HTTP

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123889.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check the event log on your domain server which in your case is the Small Business Server. Maybe some malware (Conficker?) is compromising your security and hammers your server with login attempts in order to break into your accounts.

Comment: thank you for reply

i check the event log on the domain server ,but there is no malware
on it. 


Does anyone have any further ideas?

many thanks!